# Space between Image CSS

Tags: html, css

```css
div#columncontents {
  background: black;
}

img.colimg03 {
  position: relative;
  right: -70px;
}

img.colimg02 {
  position: relative;
  right: -40px;
}
```

```html
<div id="columncontents">
  <div class="columnimage">
    <img class="colimg01" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSVuJjUob_gNDIGlo71Z9zkBGpFhizBoKUOmaVcv2mWB9ANu50d1g">
    <img class="colimg02" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSVuJjUob_gNDIGlo71Z9zkBGpFhizBoKUOmaVcv2mWB9ANu50d1g">
    <img class="colimg03" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSVuJjUob_gNDIGlo71Z9zkBGpFhizBoKUOmaVcv2mWB9ANu50d1g">
    <img class="colimg04" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSVuJjUob_gNDIGlo71Z9zkBGpFhizBoKUOmaVcv2mWB9ANu50d1g">
    <img class="colimg05" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSVuJjUob_gNDIGlo71Z9zkBGpFhizBoKUOmaVcv2mWB9ANu50d1g">
    <img class="colimg06" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSVuJjUob_gNDIGlo71Z9zkBGpFhizBoKUOmaVcv2mWB9ANu50d1g">
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, I have separated the `img class` for each picture and set their `position : relative` and `right` to desire value. 
But its seems like long and hard way, becasue I have about 12 picture. 
I want to perfectly align with the `DIV columncontents` with 4 X 4 (4 image top and 4 image bottom) 
Image should be perfectly align with the container. Is there anyother way to 
achieve this feat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex) for this. By nature, flexbox is also responsive.

UPDATE: margin added for extra space

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#columncontents {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: blue; /* For visibility only */
}

div {
  width: 23%;
  margin: 1rem 0;
}

img {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="columncontents">
  <div><img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSVuJjUob_gNDIGlo71Z9zkBGpFhizBoKUOmaVcv2mWB9ANu50d1g"></div>
  <div><img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSVuJjUob_gNDIGlo71Z9zkBGpFhizBoKUOmaVcv2mWB9ANu50d1g"></div>
  <div><img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSVuJjUob_gNDIGlo71Z9zkBGpFhizBoKUOmaVcv2mWB9ANu50d1g"></div>
  <div><img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSVuJjUob_gNDIGlo71Z9zkBGpFhizBoKUOmaVcv2mWB9ANu50d1g"></div>
  <div><img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSVuJjUob_gNDIGlo71Z9zkBGpFhizBoKUOmaVcv2mWB9ANu50d1g"></div>
  <div><img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSVuJjUob_gNDIGlo71Z9zkBGpFhizBoKUOmaVcv2mWB9ANu50d1g"></div>
  <div><img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSVuJjUob_gNDIGlo71Z9zkBGpFhizBoKUOmaVcv2mWB9ANu50d1g"></div>
  <div><img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSVuJjUob_gNDIGlo71Z9zkBGpFhizBoKUOmaVcv2mWB9ANu50d1g"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Any Chance I can have some spacing in middle? Like top image and bottom image?

Comment: @ジョシアヌズ I added margin around the image containers (div).

Comment: Wait you changed the `IMG CLASS` to `DIV TAG` .. is it necessary? like without changing to `DIV`

Comment: There's no other way to ensure proper image sizing and ensuring there will be 4 images per row.

Comment: Thank you Sir. I ll do by `DIV` Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

the best way do this `bootstrap grid system`

```css
.img-box{
  border:1px solid #000;
   margin-left:10px;
  margin-top:10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4 img-box">
            <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSVuJjUob_gNDIGlo71Z9zkBGpFhizBoKUOmaVcv2mWB9ANu50d1g" alt="">

    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 img-box">
           <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSVuJjUob_gNDIGlo71Z9zkBGpFhizBoKUOmaVcv2mWB9ANu50d1g" alt="">

    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 img-box">
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSVuJjUob_gNDIGlo71Z9zkBGpFhizBoKUOmaVcv2mWB9ANu50d1g" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 img-box">
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSVuJjUob_gNDIGlo71Z9zkBGpFhizBoKUOmaVcv2mWB9ANu50d1g" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 img-box">
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSVuJjUob_gNDIGlo71Z9zkBGpFhizBoKUOmaVcv2mWB9ANu50d1g" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 img-box">
            <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSVuJjUob_gNDIGlo71Z9zkBGpFhizBoKUOmaVcv2mWB9ANu50d1g" alt="">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Live Preview](https://codepen.io/RammmohanBandaru/pen/aaGxRJ)

Hope it solves your problem !!

Comment: Thankyou for the reply. I did exactly what you mentioned, but the right hand side of the image cant be align with DIV, I did further `margin-right` but the images goes down. Screenshot [here](https://ibb.co/jeEJPp)

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want to do? But make sure all of your images are having same dimension.

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.container > img {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img class="colimg01" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSVuJjUob_gNDIGlo71Z9zkBGpFhizBoKUOmaVcv2mWB9ANu50d1g">
  <img class="colimg02" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSVuJjUob_gNDIGlo71Z9zkBGpFhizBoKUOmaVcv2mWB9ANu50d1g">
  <img class="colimg03" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSVuJjUob_gNDIGlo71Z9zkBGpFhizBoKUOmaVcv2mWB9ANu50d1g">
  <img class="colimg04" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSVuJjUob_gNDIGlo71Z9zkBGpFhizBoKUOmaVcv2mWB9ANu50d1g">
  <img class="colimg05" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSVuJjUob_gNDIGlo71Z9zkBGpFhizBoKUOmaVcv2mWB9ANu50d1g">
  <img class="colimg06" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSVuJjUob_gNDIGlo71Z9zkBGpFhizBoKUOmaVcv2mWB9ANu50d1g">
  <img class="colimg06" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSVuJjUob_gNDIGlo71Z9zkBGpFhizBoKUOmaVcv2mWB9ANu50d1g">
  <img class="colimg06" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSVuJjUob_gNDIGlo71Z9zkBGpFhizBoKUOmaVcv2mWB9ANu50d1g">
</div>
```

Comment: This method increased my picture size, I would love to see spaces between rather than to increase picture size because it will kinda show teary image.